# Using spring 6.x with spring-boot 2.7.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an application which has spring-web 5.3.21 security vulnerability.  The security scanner suggest to upgrade spring-web to version 6.0.x.

Currently, my application is using spring-boot-starter-parent version 2.7.1.

**My question is whether it's possible to only upgrade spring to version 6.0.x but leaving spring-boot at 2.7.1.**  I was told that I will need to use spring-boot-starter-parent 3.0.x in order for the application to work correctly.

I'm just trying to minimize the changes as much as I can.  When I upgraded spring-web to 6.0.x, I got several compile-time errors and I had to update my code to get rid of these errors.

However, when I also change spring-boot-starter-parent to 3.0.x, I got even more errors during compile-time.

The application was written several years ago and I'm not 100% familiar with it so I want to make as little code changes as possible.

Comment: security scanner driven development seems not to be a good idea. FYI, OEL of Spring 5.3.x is 31 Dec 2024, that is barely possible the real security vulnerability was fixed in spring 6, but not in spring 5.3

Comment: Spring Boot versions are pretty tightly coupled to Spring versions. While you could probably change a patch version, even changing minor versions could lead to unexpected errors during runtime like `MethodNotFoundError` and similar errors / exceptions. If there really is a big vulnerability issue, I'd expect it to be fixed early next year. Spring Boot 2.7 is still maintained until next November, and apparently Spring itself even longer.

Comment: We're told to remove any "high" security vulnerabilities before migrating to AWS cloud.  Currently, there is no exception.  We've been doing this fixes with other libraries but this one requires to jump to 6.0.x from 5.x.x.  I'm seeing errors that just  keep popping up after I upgraded.

Comment: @escee999 following that logic you need to shutdown your application when next security vulnerability will be discovered in spring. I would suggest you to provide some details about vulnerability (CVE ID), rather than continue discussing your requirements

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov.  Unfortunately that's impossible for our environment as the scan occurs during build time.  If a vulnerability is detected, we're to fix it.  It's just how we operate where I work.

Comment: I don't think it has been fixed in Spring 6 only (if it is a severe vulnerability). Just update to a newer version of Spring 5.x. (and consider that your scanner might be wrong and check whether you're actually impacted)

Comment: @dan1st We will proceed with full upgrade to spring 6 and spring boot 3.  That's our future direction.  We're okay for now.

Answer (score 2):

So, seems like the best way to go is to move to spring boot 3 when upgrading to spring 6.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

first things first:

**What to do**

You do not need to migrate the Spring version (and it is not a good idea). You are using Spring Boot 2.7.1. Which was released in June 22. Right now you can use Spring Boot 2.7.7 released in Dec 22.

Since you did not provide a CVE, i cannot say for sure that this version does not contain your vulnerability, but i checked the findings on this version and it does not contain anything critical other than a few very exotic vulnerabilities in dependencies that you probably don't use.

**Versions of Maven modules**

A few things about changing versions for modules and the possible impact. Most maven modules try follow semantic naming conventions as good as possible.

This means that number on the left is the most significant and the number on the right is the least significant. Many follow [the conventions from oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm), but some skip the less important version number like build or increment/patch.

The first number is the major version and indicates - as the name suggests - a major change that is possibly breaking and not backwards compatible. The second number is the minor version and **should** contain no breaking changes to the core functionality and **should** provide backwards compatibility. The third number is for security patches - they **should** not affact your applications functionality at all.

For you this means that upgrading Spring Boot to 2.7.7 will apply all the security patches for Spring Boot 2 and not affect your application at all. An upgrade to Spring Framework 6.0.0 on the other side is applying a breaking change, so the impact is much higher. This should be true for all your dependencies.

You are right, that changing the Spring Framework version manually is probably a bad idea, specially with a major Spring version. There is a reason why the Spring upgrade to 6.x.x is also a major upgrade for Spring Boot.

Besides the incompatibilities in used classes and interfaces from the Spring Core and other dependencies, Spring 6.0.0 moves to Java 17 and Jakarta EE9.

So this would most certainly require changes on the code level. If you dont migrate the code from javax.* to jakarta.* it is very likely that you will be either missing the dependencies, since they are removed from the starter (not parent pom.xml dependecy management) or your application may behave differently (e.g. because Spring is using the validation API from jakarta while you annotated your classes with the javax annotations).

I hope this helps also with the rest of your upgrades.

Comment: The security vulnerability is in spring-web and this exists in all spring-web 5.x.x versions.  The fix seems to be in spring-web 6.x.x.  Because of this, we have to switch to spring 6 and spring-boot 3 to keep things running smoothly based on what I have read.

Comment: Well, you might consider this blog post from Spring: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24434#issuecomment-744519525